# Generating complex unitary matrix with a given column

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, unitary-matrices

I'm looking for a way to generate a complex unitary matrix in which the last column is given. I will appreciate any tips and hints.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Graham-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) can be used to orthonormalize a set of linearly independent vectors in any inner product space.  I assume the given vector $v$ is a unit vector, so not all its components are $0$.  Say entry $k\neq 0$.  Then make the fisrt $n-1$ columns equal to $$e_1,e_2,\dots,e_{k-1},e_{k+1},\dots,e_n$$ where $_k$ is the $k$th natural basis vector, so that the columns are linearly independent, and apply Graham-Schmidt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Based on the link you provided let's say we are just given v1, but to derive $e_k$ we need to have $v_k$ am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you should take the natural basis vectors as the $v_k$.  My notation conflicts with on the wiki, I'm afraid.

Comment: oh sorry, I understood. Many thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark, so that it no longer shows as unresolved.